# Will disabling my network's SSID broadcast cause my WPA encryption to be disabled?

Tags: security, networking, routers

I encountered this message when I tried to disable the SSID broadcast of my home network. Does this mean that my router's Wi-Fi connection will no longer be encrypted?

[image: Screenshot]

Sorry I'm pretty new to networking but any help/guidance or further reading is much appreciated!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Internet of Things is primarily for questions about *connecting* these devices together; you'll get a better answer for this question at [Super User](http://superuser.com/) (you can just re-ask there and delete this). It'll also be helpful to specify the router model when you repost this, so you get a proper answer.

Comment: Thanks, I thought this was appropriate for this stack as it has to do with wi-fi security for all of my devices. I feel this issue does not only apply to my computer, but concerns any device I connect to my network.

Comment: It probably *could* be on-topic if you rewrote it emphasising that aspect; at the minute though, it just seems like a router issue, which is why I voted to close. I think you'd be best to ask at Super User primarily because this is a technical question about the router itself - the devices you connect won't really matter. You're welcome to edit this to clarify though, and if you make the link to IoT clear, I'll happily vote to reopen.

Comment: Gotcha. Considering my question was answered, I guess I'll just go ahead and delete. But I would rather leave it here (closed) if deleting it will take away reputation from the user who answered

Comment: You can't delete (and don't need to!) since there is an upvoted answer. Although it's off-topic here, since it does have an answer there's no harm leaving it around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the connection will still be encrypted, but the services that depend on it like WPS (Wireless Protected Setup) won't work. WPS is a simple way to setup the WIFI connection by pressing a button in the router after setting the connecting device into WPS mode, but when the SSID is not being broadcasted the device can't find it and WPS won't Work. The encryption mode is WPA or WPA2 not WPS.

To connect without the SSID you will have to type the SSID manually everytime you want to set up a new connection.